# How to maximize a window on the second screen without blink?

Tags: c#, wpf, multiscreen

I'm now writing a program showing different windows two screens.And I need to maximize the both two.Here problem comes:

```
Window2 win2=new Windows2();
win2.Top=0;
win2.Left=Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Left;

//win2.WindowState=WindowState.Maximized;  //the second one show on the first screen
win2.show();
//win2.WindowState=WindowState.Maximized;  //the second screen will show a block window which is not full-screen.Then show the Maximization process as a blink.
```

As I write in the code,if I maximize the window before show(),it will show on the first screen(set the maximized state in XAML is the same).But maximizing it after showing it will show the Maximization process as a blink.IS there any way can deal with the problem?

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop the transition effect and just go from normal to maximised in the one step?

Comment: Yeah,I want to know if there is a way to maximaize in one step.And I want to know why maxizizing first will cause the window show in the wrong place.